# What is the best browser printing library, plugin, or snippet for javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, printing-web-page

I'm trying to print a section of a web page and there are multiple css files, and several of those files contribute to the "print" media type. Some of the plugins I've seen assume that you only have one media="print" css file and that's all it needs. I have looked at PrintArea and jsprint and am not very impressed by either of them, I believe I can tweak them to get what I need, but I'm hoping there is a better library out there that I have yet to discover.

Comment: in my case http://printjs.crabbly.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [printThis](https://jasonday.github.io/printThis/#nada). It comes loaded with several options, such as load css.

`$("#mySelector").printThis({
  debug: false,               // show the iframe for debugging
  importCSS: true,            // import page CSS
  importStyle: false,         // import style tags
  printContainer: true,       // grab outer container as well as the contents of the selector
  loadCSS: "path/to/my.css",  // path to additional css file - use an array [] for multiple
  pageTitle: "",              // add title to print page
  removeInline: false,        // remove all inline styles from print elements
  printDelay: 333,            // variable print delay
  header: null,               // prefix to html
  footer: null,               // postfix to html
  base: false ,               // preserve the BASE tag, or accept a string for the URL
  formValues: true,           // preserve input/form values
  canvas: false,              // copy canvas elements (experimental)
  doctypeString: "...",       // enter a different doctype for older markup
  removeScripts: false,       // remove script tags from print content
  copyTagClasses: false       // copy classes from the html & body tag
});`

Comment: This is a tool that I have used and it's very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at [PrintArea's source](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.PrintArea.js_4.txt), and it seems that it does take into account multiple stylesheets. It would help if you told us what exactly you don't like about the libraries.

Also, I'm not sure how much more you'll be able to accomplish with a JS-only solution than the a plugin such as PrintArea already does.

Comment: By JS-only as an option, I just didn't want some other library introduced into the solution like prototype.js or the like. And for other features, I was looking for more options, perhaps formatting, perhaps table layout features for reports, or more UI features that dialog the user options about the print job. Just something more robust.